# Docusign The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying the following code [as mentioned here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email),

```
public string loginApi(string usr, string pwd)
{
// we set the api client in global config when we configured the client 
ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + usr + "\", \"Password\":\"" + pwd + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + "\"}";
Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

// we will retrieve this from the login() results
string accountId = null;

// the authentication api uses the apiClient (and X-DocuSign-Authentication header) that are set in Configuration object
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

// find the default account for this user
foreach (LoginAccount loginAcct in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
{
    if (loginAcct.IsDefault == "true")
    {
        accountId = loginAcct.AccountId;
        break;
    }
}
if (accountId == null)
{ // if no default found set to first account
    accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
}
return accountId;
}
```

It's not working, I wrapped it with a try catch and noticed this error,

```
Error calling Login: {

"errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",

"message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled."

}
```

When I look at the fiddler,

[image]

Request is going to www.docusign.net where I want to send it to `https://demo.docusign.net`. How can I change the Base Uri for this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured out the issue. Error message is misleading.

Step 1 - Seems like I need to build the configuration object.

```
 ApiClient client = new ApiClient(basePath:  "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration(client);
```

Step 2 - Need to set the auth header

```
cfg.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```

Step 3 Pass it onto the constructor of Api

```
 AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(cfg);
```

Comment: I had an authentication issue presenting itself in the unofficial .NET Core NuGet package only; but instantiating a new Configuration instance as you highlighted seems to have solved it. Thx :D